# Reactjs - OnClick modal popup on its own

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning Reactjs and faced with a small problem.

Inside a table cell, I created a button and onclick, it should popup a modal.

```
<td className="">
    <div className="radio">
    {(() => {
            return (item.ElectionOptions.split(",").map((item1, index1) =>
            <label key={index1} className="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" id={index} value={item1}
                checked={item.Election===item1}
                onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                />{item1}
            </label>
            ))
    })()}
    </div>
    <div>
        {(() => {
            if (roleUpdate) {
                return (<button fontSize="20px" data-toggle="modal" onClick={this.handleEditOptions(item)}>Edit Options</button>)
            }
        })()}
    </div>
</td>
```

The handleEditOption is created separately:

```
handleEditOptions = (item) => {
        var modal = (<VotingOptionModal resolutiondata = {item} />);
        ReactDOM.render(modal, document.getElementById('x-modal'));

    }
```

Problem is: when I reload the page, the popup modal appeared on its own (which should not happen), as if I already clicked on the button. Furthermore, I subsequently closed the modal, and then clicked on the button, the modal does not appear. 
I think something is wrong with the event handler. But not sure how I should fix it.

Please kindly help. Thank you.

Comment: This is a bit more complex example than these usually are, but:you're calling, rather than referencing, a function in your `onClick`. You need a wrapper function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
return (<button fontSize="20px" data-toggle="modal" onClick={this.handleEditOptions(item)}>Edit Options</button>)
```

you're doing `onClick={this.handleEditOptions(item)}` which is running the function.

Instead, try `onClick={() => this.handleEditOptions(item)}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick={() => this.handleEditOptions(item)}
```

will fix this.

`onClick` expects a function as value. Writing `onClick={this.handleEditOptions(item)}` gives onClick the result of `this.handleEditOptions(item)` as a value.

So the workaround here is to wrap this method call into an anonymous function

Answer (score 0):

When you write `functionName()`, the function gets called and the function runs. Whereas, if you write `functionName` alone, the value of the function gets passed, and it will be ran `onClick`. So you can either write

`onClick={() => handleEditOptions(item)}`

In this an anonymous function is passed to the `onClick`, and the function will be ran only on Click.